# Why does my if statement get skipped over?

Tags: python

I have tried to run my code and when it gets to the calculation section, it skips the code? anyone have any tips? [The code in question]

```
print("AJ'S circle calculator")
R = int(input("What is your radius? "))
I = int(input("Solving for area(1), Or Circumference(2), "))
if I == [1]:
    A = 3.141*R**2
    print(A)
elif I == [2] :
    C = 2*3.141*R  
    print(C)
```

I have tried turning all of the integers to variables, minimize variables, and what not, but it does not work!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include relevant code in the body of the question rather than posting screenshots of code. Screenshots make it much harder for others to work with your code, and consequently make it much harder for us to help out!

Comment: `["1"]` is never going to come out of `int()`.

Comment: it says that untill I get 10 reputation, I cant get an emeded image in, only a link to said image

Comment: The idea is not to use images at all - post your code in the question.

Comment: You can always [edit] your question to update it's contents. In this case: copy your code and paste it here so we can work with it.

Comment: That said, what do you think `int(input(...)` is doing? What kind of value do you expect that to return? What kind of value are you then comparing against? Is `["1"]` an `int`? (hint hint)

Comment: and int(*input(...)) worked in my previous code, I will put it up to show, but just the relevednt section

Comment: Z = int(input("What is the value of Z? "))           this code works

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `if I in [1]` and `if I == [1]` ?

Comment: FYI: the code you posted doesn't match the code in the original screenshot, but will still result in an error for much the same reason as I mentioned above

Comment: to slothrops question, yes. If i == 1 is if I's value is 1, while if I in [1] is asking is I matchin any value in the list

Comment: Cool. So that's why the code in your question (with `if I == [1]`) didn't work, but the code in your earlier comment (with things like `if x in ['Y', 'y']` from what I remember) did work. It's the difference between `==` and `in`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're casting `input()` to an integer, but then comparing that value to a single-element list of strings `["1"]` instead of the integer value `1`. Try this instead:

```
print("AJ'S circle calculator")
R = int(input("What is your radius? "))
I = int(input("Solving for area(1), Or Circumference(2), "))

if I == 1:  # compare against 1 here
    A = 3.141 * R ** 2
    print(A)
elif I == 2:  # compare against 2 here
    C = 2 * 3.141 * R  
    print(C)
```

That said, since the value of `I` isn't being used as an integer at all, you can skip the `int()` call on it and simply compare the string value directly

```
print("AJ'S circle calculator")
R = int(input("What is your radius? "))
# no need to convert to 'int' here
I = input("Solving for area(1), Or Circumference(2), ")

if I == '1':
    A = 3.141 * R ** 2
    print(A)
elif I == '2':
    C = 2 * 3.141 * R  
    print(C)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are taking an input in variable I and converting it into an integer.

In the condition you have specified

```py
if I == ['1']:
    // steps to calculate area
elif I == ['2']:
    // steps to calculate area
```

where it is comparing an integer with a list of string. You should compare an integer with an integer value

You change it to

```py
if I == 1:
    // steps to calculate area
elif I == 2:
    // steps to calculate area
```